# Excratct Discord Private Messages into TEXT

Tags: javascript, python, discord

[plannedApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w61m.png)

Hello ! In the photo above, I have a small plan, that I have in mind but don't know how to take it on.
I like to joke around with some friends, and we delete the messages after sending them.Thing is, if I am not at the PC or,I am not very quick about I lose every way of seeing the message, therefore, I want to make this plan happen. This should be useful in more scenarios but right now its a little play thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide context on what you've treid/ researched so far. This is for help or questions about your project not for getting an application for free

Comment: I am not trying to get an application for free, in fact i want to do this myself, but i do not have the experience with machine learning to do this and i do not know where to start. Even linking a tutorial would be helpful as i never have done this before

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is a `self-bot`. This kind of bot to automate a user account is [forbidden by discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-).

An alternative solution would be to create a private group with your friend and your bot. Your bot could catch the messages, save them and make them availble through e.g. private messages from you.

[This tutorial](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/) seems like good starting point for such a bot.